# Convert Cell array with date values to string in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have the following datset stored as a .csv file:

```
28/03/2016 07:20:18.352,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.34,6.35,7.09,-0.01,NaN,NaN,NaN,22.35,NaN,NaN,NaN,8.16,11.29,25.88,NaN,NaN,5.08,NaN,14.36,1873.75,894.5,20,1,28,33,7,81
28/03/2016 07:20:18.883,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.34,6.35,7.09,-0.01,NaN,NaN,NaN,29.02,NaN,NaN,NaN,5.82,11.29,25.49,1.19,NaN,5.37,NaN,14.36,1873.75,825.75,27,1,28,33,9,81
28/03/2016 07:20:19.193,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.34,6.35,7.09,-0.01,NaN,NaN,NaN,37.65,NaN,NaN,NaN,5.85,11.29,25.49,1.19,NaN,7.83,NaN,14.36,1873.75,740.5,18,1,28,33,9,81
28/03/2016 07:20:19.515,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.34,6.35,7.09,-0.01,NaN,NaN,NaN,37.65,NaN,NaN,NaN,5.74,11.28,25.49,1.19,NaN,8.41,NaN,14.36,1873.75,770.5,14.5,1,28,33,10,81
28/03/2016 07:20:19.845,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.34,6.35,7.09,-0.01,NaN,NaN,NaN,35.69,NaN,NaN,NaN,6.18,11.28,25.49,1.62,NaN,8.56,NaN,14.36,1873.75,810,7.5,1,28,33,10,81
28/03/2016 07:20:20.173,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.34,6.35,7.09,-0.01,NaN,NaN,NaN,35.29,NaN,NaN,NaN,6.17,11.28,25.49,1.62,NaN,8.12,NaN,14.36,1873.75,854.5,10,1,28,33,10,81
```

I open the file usind `importdata` command, as follows:

```
data = importdata('trackLog-2016-mar-28_07-19-19.csv');
>> date_string = strcat (data.textdata(2:end,1),{' '}, data.textdata(2:end,2));
```

The variable `data` is stored as struct file.

When I try to convert to numbers using `datenum`, it returns:

```
xdate = datenum(date_string, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF');
??? Error using ==> datenum at 182
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

Previously, I wrote the command:

```
date_string = strcat (data.textdata(2:end,1),{' '}, data.textdata(2:end,2));
```

How can I get this over?

Comment: Works fine for me... what version of MATLAB?

Comment: @Dan Matlab R2010a. I'll check this out again...

Comment: I tried it on `date_string = {'28/03/2016 07:19:19.592 '; '28/03/2016 07:19:19.824 '; '28/03/2016 07:19:20.053 '}`

Comment: @Dan I'll edit the question

Comment: @Dan I tried using 'char' and a cell string was generated, but 'datenum failed'.

Comment: Dan's example also works for me.

Comment: @Mathias W. Ok. Problem solved. I took the 100 first lines of .csv file and it worked fine.